# Time/Space Trade-Off in Dynamic Array Allocation in Heap vs. Stack?

Tags: c#, arrays, language-agnostic, programming-languages, computer-science

I've been working through my Programming Languages book (which tends to get a lot more technical in concepts than I would have ever dreamed of going) when I came to this question:

**What are the trade-offs in time and space, when the allocation of dynamics arrays occurs in the run-time stack rather than the heap?**

In my mind, I suppose when allocation would occur in the stack, it would take up less space, but more time, whereas in a heap, it would take longer to sort through, but less size needed for allocation?

Can anyone confirm/destroy my thought process on this?

Comment: When you have a tag like `language-agnostic`, you dont need a tag like `c#`

Comment: C# is what I'm most familiar with. Just seemed appropriate to tackle from a C# perspective in thought.

Comment: This is going to have pretty significant differences between languages; it cannot really be answered in a language agnostic manor.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see why an array (or something) should use more or less space depending on in what part of the memory it is allocated. Also, unless heap allocation is implemented in a malloc like fashion, the allocation is nothing more than fixing the start address and bumping a pointer.

The real trade-off is the possible life cycle of the object/array created. While it can outlive the function/method it is created on the heap, it certainly can't when stack allocated.

The only point where you could save some CPU cycles is through deallocation of the object. A stack object goes away without extra effort, when the stack frame is dropped. A heap object, OTOH, will have to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

@ingo is correct. I would also like to add that in general, the size of a heap is orders of magnitude larger than a stack size. So one trade-off would be how much space is available for an array when it is allocated in either space, for instance if I have to create a 300 Mb array, the heap would probably be my best option.

Comment: `the size of a heap is orders of magnitude larger than a stack size` That really depends on the language (or even implementation of it).

Comment: @Servy Granted, but that's why I said "in general". It is in particular true for C# which tag is used in this question.

Answer (score 0):

For space:

Typically memory allocator round up the amount of memory needed, for alignment purposed.

So there is some memory overhead using the heap. Some compilers might do the same with stack based array too. It all depends on the specifics.

For time:

Memory allocators have a time overhead which could be significant.

For stack based, it is usually changing the stack pointer, which is pretty fast.

Again, specifics.